# SQL sum after group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, volusion

I have a query that I built for Volusion, which is very limited in SQL abilities, such as I can't use temp tables, or even variables... which is how I would normally try to do this task.

but, I have this query which gives me the info I need, but I have to work with it in Excel after running... and I'd like to get the query to get me the results I need.

What I ultimately need is the cost/profit by google_gender and by rep... summed.
Is there a way I can accomplish this without variables or temp tables?

here's my current query:

```
SELECT
    Products_Joined.Google_Gender,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Customers.SalesRep_CustomerID,379646,'Dan'),658024,'Owen'),643352,'Mary'),584310,'Pete') as SalesRep,
    SUM(OrderDetails.ProductPrice)*OrderDetails.Quantity as TotalSold,
    SUM(OrderDetails.Vendor_Price)*OrderDetails.Quantity as VendorCost,
    SUM(OrderDetails.ProductPrice)*OrderDetails.Quantity-(OrderDetails.Vendor_Price)*OrderDetails.Quantity as Profit
FROM
    Products_Joined, OrderDetails, Orders, Customers
WHERE
    Products_Joined.ProductCode=OrderDetails.ProductCode 
    AND OrderDetails.OrderID=Orders.OrderID 
    AND Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
    AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '05/01/16 00:00' and '05/31/16 23:59'
    AND Customers.SalesRep_CustomerID in ('379646' , '658024' , '643352' , '584310')
    AND Orders.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
GROUP BY    
    Products_Joined.Google_Gender,
    OrderDetails.Quantity,
    OrderDetails.Vendor_Price,
    OrderDetails.ProductPrice,
    Customers.SalesRep_CustomerID
```

because the query has to pull item information from OrderDetails, to get the "sold price" it lines out each order# and sku in the resulting file, which i don't need, I just need the total amount by each google_gender, by rep. and there's only going to be the 4 reps :)

Comment: would be easier to answer if you give some sample data and describe, what the problem is with your current query

Comment: Sure it can be done. Here is a great to start getting an answer. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Also, you really should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for well over 20 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: swe, the current query works properly. but I want to sum the data in SQL so I don't have to do work in excel after running the report.

Comment: You've got sum's, what's wrong with those? Also, don't you have a table with the sale-reps names? You don't want to do a similar `replace` when you have dozens of sale-reps...

Comment: @HoneyBadger yes those sums work, but the report still line items out each sku/order... I jsut need the total amount per google gender, per rep, I dont need the individual line item data, but I have to pull it to get the "sold by" cost.

Comment: Mild curiosity, if `Total Sold` is "number of units", shouldn't that be `SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity)`?

Comment: Total Sold isn't a number of units, but a total $ amount sold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the SUM per gender/rep you need to get rid of the other grouping levels. Without any schema or data I'm just guessing, but this might give you what you want;

```
SELECT
    Products_Joined.Google_Gender,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Customers.SalesRep_CustomerID,379646,'Dan'),658024,'Owen'),643352,'Mary'),584310,'Pete') as SalesRep,
    SUM(OrderDetails.ProductPrice*OrderDetails.Quantity) as TotalSold,
    SUM(OrderDetails.Vendor_Price*OrderDetails.Quantity) as VendorCost,
    SUM(OrderDetails.ProductPrice*OrderDetails.Quantity)-SUM(OrderDetails.Vendor_Price*OrderDetails.Quantity) as Profit
FROM
    Products_Joined, OrderDetails, Orders, Customers
WHERE
    Products_Joined.ProductCode=OrderDetails.ProductCode 
    AND OrderDetails.OrderID=Orders.OrderID 
    AND Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
    AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '05/01/16 00:00' and '05/31/16 23:59'
    AND Customers.SalesRep_CustomerID in ('379646' , '658024' , '643352' , '584310')
    AND Orders.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
GROUP BY    
    Products_Joined.Google_Gender,
    Customers.SalesRep_CustomerID
```

Note that all the OrderDetails are inside the SUM functions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that first.... this is what I get when I try that: Your SQL is invalid: Column 'OrderDetails.Quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I've changed your SUM expressions, not just the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: wow ok, I see it now. that does work, that is what I needed, thank you so much!